# How to upload geojson file in django postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views, geodjango

I would like to import a geojson file (Edge) in my postgresql database. I have a form for uploading the file. My problem is how to handle foreigns keys network, target, source and roadtype. Source and target must be Node instance. the file will be download inside the network page(pk).
Could you please help me?
models.py

```
class Edge(models.Model):
    lanes = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField('Edge Name', max_length=200, blank=False)
    road_type = models.ForeignKey(RoadType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    source = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    network = models.ForeignKey(RoadNetWork, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my geojson file is like that

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Out 1 - E",
                "lanes": 1,
                "source": 1,
                "target": 2,
                "param1": 3000.0,
                "road_type": 2
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would have to make a forloop and then pass the value you want from the foreignkeys and save it as a geojson

```
edge = Edge.objects.all()

geo_json = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {"type": "name", "properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}},
    "features": [
        ]
    }
tot_json = []

for t in edge:
    gg = //you source of geolocation for the object, reprojected or transformed if its the case//
    p_json = {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry" : {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [gg[0], gg[1]],
                    },
                "properties" : {
                    'id':t.pk,
                    'name':t.name,
                    'lanes':t.lanes, //or t.lanes."the value you want to pass"
                    'source':t.source,,
                    'target':t.target,,
                    'param1':t.param1,,
                    'road_type':t.road_type,

         },
         }


    tot_json.append(p_json)
geo_json['features']= tot_json
```